# Getting new items for an activity stream that supports item "bumping"

Tags: ajax, algorithm, language-agnostic, user-experience

Let's say we have an activity stream for user X, something like on Facebook. Each activity can be commented, and such comment "bumps" the activity upper in the stream, i.e. activity now appears in a stream with date/time of its last comment.

Going from idea to realization, every few minutes user browser polls for the new activities and show them at the top of the activity list presented to the user.

Now, because of the "bumping", activity items can easily become reordered. As a consequence, the following can occur:

**Before update**

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

**After update**

```
Item 3
------
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

This is because I poll for activity items that are younger than the lastest item already on the list. I could of course remove *Item 3* from the "old" list, but if there is a lot of "bumping" the user can be easily lost in what's going on. Moreover, in extreme case in which all old items become "bumped", all new (polled/loaded) items are in fact old items, just in different order. In such case, user could be easily puzzled why the number of visible activity items hasn't increased.

Is there any good solution to this problem?

Comment: seems like more a user-interface/user-experience problem than an algorithm one to me

Comment: I agree. To be honest I wasn't sure what tags to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User should be able to sort theirs activity based on the time the activity is created, and the time of the last comment to the activity. In both cases the user should have visual cue that activity has new unread comments, and this cue is reset when user visits activity.

Comment: I was thinking about additional questions to ask you, and then I was enlightened that I oversimplified the problem in my head. If there can be new activities, as well as old (existing) activities can be bumped, then I should tell user exactly that, e.g.: "4 new messages, 3 messages below has new comments" and when user clicks it, I should animate the activity items to show exactly what's going on. Thank you for shaking my brain cells!